# Is there a open source test manager that supports python, can analyze logs and run test suites?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, jenkins, quality-assurance, jira

I am looking for a Open Source **Test Automation Manager** tool.

I used to work with an Oracle Solaris internal tool named "Beast" which had, among other things, the following capabilities:

---

1. It had a browser UI, so its not OS dependent.
2. It's scriptable. You can run any type of test by running a script to launch it.
3. It used parameter files to populate the tests' data. You provide a file listing key-value pairs to populate the test's data.
4. It collects your logs, either files or run time terminal. It stored the logs for history reference and allowed access to previous runs' results.
5. It analyzes the logs using user defined symptoms. This is basically running complex conditional grep(s) on the log to extract failures\errors\bugs.
6. It allows building complex test suites by combining smaller tests into a single scenario. Tests are triggered to run only if the tests they depended on were successful.

---

It would be great if:

1. it could be triggered to run tests from Jenkins.
2. it could connect to Jira.
3. the tool is an industry standard. I saw many tools inventing their own scripting languages, saving test cases in odd formats.

---

What Test Managers are you using?

Do your environments provide the features above?

Answer (score 1):

Robot Framework (a very feature rich framework that has fairly strict methods of creating tests) and Nose (more like JUnit). Jira integration would have to be via a rest endpoint